# How to transfer the coordinates of a shape from class 1 to class 2 after dragging a shape

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[duplicate]

I have 2 classes. 1 class creates a rectangle and also has a drag and drop function in the 2nd class draws a line

I tried to use event to catch the move and then pass the coordinates, but could not implement it

how to pass the coordinates of rectangles from the Rect class to the Lines class and draw a line when the rectangle is moved

here is the code

js

```
var width = 1425,
    height = 1000;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

svg.attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width);


var deltaX, deltaY;

class Rect {
    constructor(x_block, y_block) {
        this.x_block = x_block;
        this.y_block = y_block;
    }

    get_rect() {
        var name = svg.append("rect")
            .attr("href", "#pointer")
            .style("fill", "aliceblue")
            .style("stroke", "grey")
            .style("stroke-width", "2")
            .attr("x", this.x_block)
            .attr("y", this.y_block)
            .attr("width", 150)
            .attr("height", 200)
            .attr("rx", 3);


        var dragHandler = d3.drag()
            .on("start", function () {
                var current = d3.select(this);
                deltaX = current.attr("x") - d3.event.x;
                deltaY = current.attr("y") - d3.event.y;
            })

            .on("drag", function () {
                d3.select(this)
                    .attr("x", d3.event.x + deltaX)
                    .attr("y", d3.event.y + deltaY);


            });

        dragHandler(svg.selectAll("rect"));


    }


}

class Lines {
    constructor(rect1, rect2) {
        this.x1_block = rect1.x_block;
        this.y1_block = rect1.y_block;
        this.x2_block = rect2.x_block;
        this.y2_block = rect2.y_block;
    }


    ad_line() {

        var line1 = svg.append("svg").append('path').attr('d', `M ${this.x1_block + 150}, ${this.y1_block + 100} Q ${(this.x2_block) - (this.x1_block)},${(this.y2_block)} ${this.x2_block},${this.y2_block + 100}`).attr('fill', 'none').attr("stroke", "red")
    }
}

var rect3 = new Rect(400, 200)
var rect4 = new Rect(850, 450)
rect3.get_rect()
rect4.get_rect()



var line_x = new Lines(rect3, rect4)
line_x.ad_line()
```

css

```
svg line{
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 2;

}
```

html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://d3js.org/d3-drag.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    <div class="svg-container">
        <svg id="click" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
            <defs>
                <g id="pointer" transform="scale(0.8)">
                    <path d="M0-1c-14.5-25.6-14.5-25.7-14.5-33.8c0-8.1,6.5-14.6,14.5-14.6s14.5,6.6,14.5,14.6C14.5-26.7,14.5-26.6,0-1z"></path>
                    <path d="M0-49c7.7,0,14,6.3,14,14.1c0,8,0,8.1-14,32.8c-14-24.7-14-24.9-14-32.8C-14-42.7-7.7-49,0-49 M0-50c-8.3,0-15,6.8-15,15.1 S-15-26.5,0,0c15-26.5,15-26.5,15-34.9S8.3-50,0-50L0-50z"></path>
                </g>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```